# im using onkeyup() to call javascript function which adds some value, while using backspace it not subtracts the value instead it adds every values

Tags: javascript

im using the below function in onkeyup() event of a textbox to add two values of textbox,  while entering every digits of numbers in textbox it adds also while deleting number digits it adds the remaining digits, . i wants to decrement the sum value while deleting digits using backspace.

```
function round_off(){
var inv=document.getElementById("invoice").value ;
var rnd_off=document.getElementById("round_off").value ;
var invo=parseFloat(inv) + parseFloat(rnd_off);
invoice.value=invo.toFixed(2);
};
```

thanks in advance

Comment: Where is the code, setting the calculated value to the field?

Comment: <input type="text" class="span2" id="round_off" onkeyup="round_off()" />
<input type="text" class="span2" id="invoice" />

Comment: these are two text fields i used in my code, added here Ankit

Comment: @ravi Do you want to decrement before or after the last digit is removed?

Comment: @Teemu i wants to decrement value after deleting every digits , because while adding every digits it adds sum value, so while deleting every digits i need to decrement sum value,

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you really need, but I guess you can start with this:

```
function round_off (e) {
    var inv = +document.getElementById('invoice').value,
        rnd_off = +document.getElementById('round_off').value,
        invo;
    if (e.keyCode === 8) { // 8 = Backspace
        invo = inv - rnd_off;
    } else {
        invo = inv + rnd_off;
    }
    invoice.value = invo.toFixed(2);
    return;
}
```

Notice also, that you'll need to pass `event` to the handler:

```
... onkeyup="round_off(event)" ...
```

Comment: hi Teemu . your code works for backspace event, but it decreases just the deleted digit, suppose we entered 11 and deletes 10's digit 1 means we need to delete 10 from final value, but it deletes just 1 from final value. please help me out, im new here.

Comment: @ravi Actually the code ignores the deleted value (ofcourse). That's why I asked you, "Do you want to decrement before or after the last digit is removed?". I suppose you need to use `keydown` for decrement (`round_off` value is not changed yet when executing handler) and `keyup` for increment (`round_off` value is changed when executing handler).

Comment: i need to decrement the value after we delete a digit, for example we have 214 and 36 in two textfields,final value is 250 in invoice field., suppose we delete last digit in 36 means final value must be 217, but in our code it is 244

Comment: hi Teemu. first im thanking you for your kind help. my problem is, for my page i have one text field named invoice, it may be 122.55 or 17775.50. for billing and cash settlement purpose i just wants to add a small value 0.45 or 0.50 and make it as 123 or 17776 for my above example, this only i wants sir

Comment: Any help at MDN? [Math.round](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/round/), [Math.floor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/floor/), [Math.ceil](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/ceil/). Also I'd suggest to use `onchange` for inputs instad of keyboard events.